# Swift spritekit set userdata

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my swift spritekit game I want to set a custom value on a sprite I try to do this like so

```
p.userData?.setValue(value: "Hello", forKey: "c")
```

But when I try this it says "Could not find an overload for 'setValue' that accepts the supplied arguments".

So the main question is:

How can I set a custom value on a sprite?

Comment: did you create and assign a NSMutableArray to userData? By default the property is nil.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first argument in a *method* does not have an external parameter name,
therefore it should be

```
p.userData?.setValue("Hello", forKey: "c")
```

or *better* (since `userData` is a `NSMutableDictionary` and no Key-Value Coding
magic is required here):

```
p.userData?.setObject("Hello", forKey: "c")
```

Note also (as just mentioned in a comment) that you have to create the dictionary
first:

```
p.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
p.userData?.setObject("Hello", forKey: "c")
```

or alternatively, assign a dictionary with your keys and values:

```
p.userData = ["c" : "Hello"]
```

Comment: Why do you have to create it first? Why is it nil by default and simply not a mutable dictionary to start with?

Comment: Because it's up to you to decide if/when you want to use it. Creating an NSMutableDictionary for every SKNode is a needless waste of resources. Another good example is the `physicsBody` property of a SKNode. No need to create a `physicsBody` by default, if physics aren't going to be utilized for that node.