# Trying to use every SKSpriteNode with a new property

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm doing a game in SpriteKit and I don't know how to link a new property (lets call it "value") to every SKSpriteNode. I've tried a few things:

-> Use a struct like this:

```
struct mySprite {
    var sprite: SKSpriteNode
    var value: CGFloat
}
```

But then I can't assign for example `sprite1.sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "picture")`

-> Trying to extend SKSpriteNode, which XCode won't let me add a new property.

-> Building a new class that inherits from SKSpriteNode adding a new property called value like this:

```
 class mySprite : SKSpriteNode {
    var value: CGFloat = 0
}
```

But then, I can't perform lines of code like:

```
let sprite : mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "picture")
```

I think I'm building the class in the wrong way.

Any ideas please? Also count I'm a little newbie in iOS programming so any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom class like this

```
class CustomSpriteNode : SKSpriteNode {
    var value: CGFloat = 0
}
```

For creating an instance of the custom class

```
let spriteNode : CustomSpriteNode = CustomSpriteNode(imageNamed: "picture.png")    
spriteNode.value = 10
```

Comment: You can simplify it slightly by leaving out the type of spriteNode and coding : let spriteNode = CustomSpriteNode(imageNamed: ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest option is to store data directly in the userData property of the SKNode.

```
mySprite.userdata = ["myValue" :"asdf" ]
```

More examples here: [Swift spritekit set userdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980980/swift-spritekit-set-userdata)

Or, as others have suggested you can subclass the Node and add your own properties.