# How to assign instance variable to SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have several `SKSpriteNode`'s called `circle1`, `circle2`, etc. I want to track how many times each one rotates using an `Int count`. Is there any way I could assign `count` to be a member of `circle1`? Something like `circle1.count = 2`, the way you would do `circle1.position = ...`? I don't want to have to create a new variable for each circle, as there are quite a few.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass SKSpriteNode and make a new class with a public property called count. Like this:

```
class Circle: SKSpriteNode {

var count:Int = 0

init() {

    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "circle")

    //Designated initializer
    super.init(texture: texture, color: SKColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())

    //initialization stuff goes here
}

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
let circle = Circle()

circle.count++
```

Or you can use [userData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property as an alternative of subclassing (quote from the docs):

> **Discussion**
>
> You use this property to store your own data in a node. For example, you might store game-specific data about each node to use
>   inside your game logic. This can be a useful alternative to creating
>   your own node subclasses to hold game data.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981180/3402095) how to work with userData.