# Random Node Generation SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am creating a game that spawns random enemies and moves them across the screen for the user to shoot in spritekit. The problem I am having is detecting when an enemy is touched. I have tried numerous different methods but nothing works. I think the problem I am having is that each spawned enemy is using the same variable. All I really want to know is how I can execute a certain code block when one of the "enemy" Sprites is touched. Here is my function for adding an enemy, I am then calling this function on a timer to add an enemy. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am lost and frustrated. Thanks in advance

```
func addEnemy() {

    let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height-150)

    possibleEnemy = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: possibleEnemies) as! [String]

    let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: possibleEnemies[0])
    let randomEnemyPosition = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 200, highestValue: Int(distance))


    let position = CGFloat(randomEnemyPosition.nextInt())

    enemy.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    enemy.name = "\(possibleEnemies[0])"
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x:-50, y: position)
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: enemy.size)
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    self.addChild(enemy)
    let animationDuration:TimeInterval = 6
    let oscillate = SKAction.oscillation(amplitude: 30, timePeriod: 4, midPoint: enemy.position)
    enemy.run(SKAction.repeatForever(oscillate))
    enemy.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: size.width, y: 0, duration: 5))
    var actionArray = [SKAction]()
    actionArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(x: self.frame.width, duration: animationDuration))
    actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
    enemy.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))


}
```

Edit: Code used to detect if enemy is touched

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {



        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if enemy.contains(location) {

            //Run code


        }
    }

}
```

Edit: Other method tried for detecting if node was touched

```
let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

if let name = touchedNode.name
{
    if name == "enemy"
    {
        //Run code
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which code are you using to detect that an enemy has been touched?

Comment: You can distinguish your enemy by setting correctly the "enemy.name" and re-checking for this name to the touching delegate methods

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I tried the above method that I think is similar to what you are saying while have the name set to "enemy" when creating an enemy

Comment: The code looks good in touchesBegan looks good. Please, check that touchesBegan is called at least once when tapping anywhere in the scene.

Comment: @xpereta yes it works with other nodes in the scene the only problem is with these randomly generate enemy nodes that is why I am so confused

Comment: @ZachFuller You have a group of enemies, probably similars, but if you want to know if a specific enemy was touched to the screen, you must make unique every enemy for example using a counter, or a string, have you think to use .userData dictionary? That could be an idea..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano I think that is my problem exactly, I am honestly very new to this whole thing and do not know of the ideas you suggested, could you please explain which would be the best and how I would go about implementing it

Comment: Check this answer for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26981180/1894067 , you could use it for you enemy node.

Comment: Okay I will try that in the morning thank you for sending it